# Pick up session later again

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

is there a possibility to preserve a session with Actions on Google?

I would like that users can leave the the current session, do something in between for a some minutes / an hour and then start with the next invocation exactly where they have been before. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't impossible, but you would have to save the state yourself (ie - there is nothing that Actions provides that would do this for you automatically).

If you're using API.AI, for example, you could save all of the current contexts in your database. When the user returned, you could see if you have saved contexts and, if so, return them in the response as current contexts (along with any voice message saying you've done so).

As far as API.AI is concerned at that point - you're at the same place you were before.